# jQuery .hover() is driving me crazy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a project that uses drop-down menus that are nested ul's, like so:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="thome" class="navtab">
    <a href="#" class="navlink lhome" id="nav_home" onclick="doCurrent('home');">HOME</a>
        <ul id="subnav_home" class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SMS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery, I've added a `.hover()` to the `.navtab` li that `.show()s` the `.submenu` ul.  The problem is that when the cursor moves into the new ul, the `.hover()`-out for the `.navtab` fires, `.hide()`ing the sub-menu, despite the fact that I have the height of the li so that it entirely wraps the `.submenu` ul.

I've tried adding a delay to the `.hide()`, but if you pass your cursor over the navtab bar quickly, you get all of the sub-menus at once.

Any solutions for me?  Here's the relevant JavaScript.  The `hide()` function is identical to `.show()` except that it shrinks the height and hides the ul (obviously).

```
$('.navtab').hover(
        function(){
            tabShowSubnav($(this).attr('id'));
        },
        function(){
            tabHideSubnav($(this).attr('id'));
    });

function tabShowSubnav(menu){
    
    var sb = '#' + menu + ' > .submenu';
    var tb = '#' + menu;
    $('.navtab').each(function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass('current_page')){
            $(tb).addClass('nav_hover');
        }
    });
    $(tb).css('height','239px');    
    $(sb).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had to go with the jQuery plugin hoverIntent, that ignores children for the purpose of mouseout.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.navtab').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).children(".submenu").show().children('.current_page').addClass("nav_hover");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).children(".submenu").hide();
    });
```

This worked for me.

Comment: what does children('current_page') do?

Comment: Nope - same problem.  If you're really quick on the draw, you can get it to not hide(), but otherwise it vanishes when you enter the submenu.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.navtab').hover(
        function() {
                    $(this).children(".submenu").show().children('current_page').addClass("nav_hover");
        },
        function() {
        });

    $(".submenu").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
```